# Python 3 - SFTP - SSH - Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, sftp

Buenas tardes compañeros,

Estaba tratando de realizar un scritp en python3.8 mediante la libria paramiko, os comento mi idea y mi codigo. Me encontrado con problemas al descargar el un fichero de mi VPS.

Datos para conexion:

```
import paramiko

    HOST = '51.83.X.XX'
    PUERTO = 22
    USUARIO = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx'
    datos = dict(hostname=HOST, port=PUERTO, username=USUARIO, password='XXXXXX')
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()


Datos_connect = dict(hostname=Host, port=Puerto, username=Usuario, password=Clave)
```

Conexion:

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(**Datos_connect)
entrada, salida, error = ssh_client.exec_command('pwd')
ruta=salida.read()
print(ruta)
```

Creamos una instancia SFTP:

```
sftp = ssh_client.open_sftp()
archivos = sftp.listdir()

for archivo in archivos:
    print(archivo)

esc_file = input('Selecciona un archivo: ')
archivo_remoto = "%(ruta)s/%(nombre)s" % dict(ruta=ruta, nombre=archivo)
```

Intento de descarga de unos los ficheros de mi VPS en mi directorio personal y me reporta un error, que os enseñare mas tarde:

```
sftp.get(archivo_remoto, 'D:\Python')
print ("copiado archivo %s." % archivo)

print(salida.read())


sftp.close()
ssh_client.close()
```

La salido del error al pasar el fichero a descargar es el siguiente:
..............................................

> *Selecciona un archivo: service_web.log Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Python\Py_sftp.py", line 28, in 
>       sftp.get(archivo_remoto, 'D:\Python')   File "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py",
>   line 801, in get
>       with open(localpath, "wb") as fl: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\Python'*

En este caso lo trato de copiar a mi disco duro d: con permisos, me esta denegando la descarga por permiso cunado realmente si los tengo, o eso creo. Algun compañero me puede orientar en donde se encuentra el error?

Ademas me gustaria aprovechar y preguntar que mejores veis en el codigo.

Muchas gracias a todos y un saludo

Comment: Un detalle, no uses nunca `"\"` para rutas de archivos, `"\"` se usa para denotar secundinas de escape (`\n`, `\t`, `\s`, `\t`, etc). Podrías escapara la barra o usar cadenas crudas, pero en ciertas situaciones también dan problemas. Usa `/` como separador, es universal.  `sftp.get(archivo_remoto, 'D:/Python')`.  En cuanto a los permisos, trata de ejecutar el script como adminstrador desde CMD a ver que tal, tu puedes tener permisos de escritura como administrador pero aparentemente el intérprete no los tiene...

Comment: He tenido en cuenta las consideraciones oportuans, escapando la ruta de destino D:\Python\Py_sftp.py y comprobar que puedo generar un archivo en dicho directorio y no tengo problema. Ejecuto el script como administrador y no me devuelve nada: `C:\Windows\system32>python3 D:\Python\Py_sftp.py

C:\Windows\system32>python D:\Python\Py_sftp.py`

Comment: se puede realizar el respaldo por directorio completo y no por archivo?